# How to resolve square of matrix substraction?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently stuck with the following step of the derivation of the Fisher criterion. Can somebody please expand and explain the following? I cannot follow the steps.

$$
=\dots$$
$$= (\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{m}_1-\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{m}_2)^2$$
$$= \mathbf{w}^T(\mathbf{m}_1-\mathbf{m}_2)(\mathbf{m}_1-\mathbf{m}_2)^T\mathbf{w}$$
$$=\dots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show this by the following procedure

$$(w^Tm_1-w^Tm_2)^2=\left[w^T(m_1-m_2) \right]^2=w^T(m_1-m_2)w^T(m_1-m_2)$$

Now, note that $w^T(m_1-m_2)$ is a scalar (row vector $\cdot$ column vector), hence we can simply transpose it without changing it.

$$(w^Tm_1-w^Tm_2)^2=w^T(m_1-m_2)\left[w^T(m_1-m_2)\right]^T=w^T(m_1-m_2)(m_1-m_2)^Tw.$$

In the last step I used $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$.

Comment: Damn I used (ab)²=a²b² from the second step on, but that need the commutative law I guess. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem! This stuff is sometimes confusing :).